# react native camera video feature how to record video

Tags: android, react-native

how do I do activate / use the video feature from https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera

Currently, I am able to take pictures but I would like to record videos instead. When I hit the Start recording text button, the app simply just crash and I have no idea how to get the error logs.

Below is the code I have written in attempt to record video

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      Platform,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      AppRegistry,
      TouchableHighlight,
    } from 'react-native';

    import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
    import Camera from 'react-native-camera'

    export default class CameraScreen extends React.Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
            tabBarLabel: 'Camera'
        };

      render() {
        return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

         <Camera 

          ref={(cam) => {
            this.camera = cam;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
          //type = {Camera.constants.Type.front}
          captureMode = {Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video}

          keepAwake={true}
          >


          <Text style={styles.capture} onPress={this.takeVid.bind(this)}> Start recording </Text>
          <Text style={styles.capture} onPress={this.stopVid.bind(this)}> Stop recording </Text>
        </Camera>
      </View>
    );
  }

  takeVid() {
    const option = {};
    //options.location = ...
    this.camera.capture({
      mode: Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video
    })
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }

  stopVid(){
   //console.log("I am pressed");
    this.camera.stopCapture();
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be doing everything correctly. Can you try changing your start and stop recording to this code from their example                          
https://gist.github.com/ShayanJavadi/915c59ce7c29ff66452c4d00b18326fb

Comment: Same thing happens, the app just crash. I'm beginning to thing I did not add the permission to my androidmanifest.xml. However, there are many different androidmanifest that I'm not sure which file should I add it in.

Comment: have you solved it? i ran into the same issue

Comment: Hi, yes. I've solved it. I did not important these 4 permission into the AndroidManifest.xml


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />